# Error with LocalAudioFile(file) returns OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, api, ffmpeg, echonest

Much like the question here http://developer.echonest.com/forums/thread/3843#reply, I am having the following error:

> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/echonest/remix/audio.py", line
>   944, in **init**
>       sampleRate=sampleRate, numChannels=numChannels)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/echonest/remix/audio.py", line
>   403, in **init**
>       self.load()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/echonest/remix/audio.py", line
>   421, in load
>       numChannels=self.numChannels, sampleRate=self.sampleRate, verbose=self.verbose)   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/echonest/remix/support/ffmpeg.py",
>   line 91, in ffmpeg
>       close_fds=(not win)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in **init**
>       errread, errwrite)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
>       raise child_exception OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I checked input and output file permissions, made sure that both files and all related file paths existed, and that I have all the relevant python tools installed. The first clue is that Subprocess.py is having trouble. Looking at ffmpeg.py on line 88, I started playing around with the Popen function call to see how and why it was misbehaving.

Solution:

After messing around with the ffmpeg.py file, I piped the input to the shell (shell=True instead of shell=False), which raised the following error:

```
check raise Run timeError(ffmpeg_install_instructions) RuntimeError: en-ffmpeg not found! Please make sure ffmpeg is installed and create a link as follows: sudo ln -s which ffmpeg /usr/local/bin/en-ffmpeg Alternatively, import echonest.remix.support.ffmpeg and modify ffmpeg.FFMPEG to name the appropriate binary.
```

So, to finalize the solution, you need to get the binary from https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-linux, which in Ubuntu 14.04 means you just need to:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
sudo ln -s `which ffmpeg` /usr/local/bin/en-ffmpeg
```

That should clear this problem right up.

Comment: While it's great that you want to post your solution, your question is not a good place for it.  If it is a good answer to the question you linked, answer it there.  If it is just a good answer to the question here, post it as an answer to your own question.

Comment: Not possible. They've closed comments on that site, and migrated to Stack Overflow, saying that everything should be tagged as echonest. And I had the same question... so should I just repeat the question in my own words?

Comment: Yes.  That would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I could have just posted the linked question, and put my answer here. But to restate, it wasn't a file existing problem, it was a not-correctly-installed-and-configured ffmpeg issue. Installing ffmpeg and putting the proper symbolic link makes everything work for me.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
sudo ln -s `which ffmpeg` /usr/local/bin/en-ffmpeg
```